# Conect a phone screen to the RPi (GPIO)?

Tags: gpio, video, screen, touchscreen

I've an old cellphone I don't use anymore (LG Secret (KF750)) and I was thinking about disassembling it in order to use its screen with the RasPi (probably with the GPIO pins ?).

It sounds nice to me but I'm a total newbie in electronic, so first I'd like to know if it's possible, do you think so ? About Wikipedia the display device is : "240 x 320, 2.4" Display 262K-color TFT LCD", maybe it helps ? I also found this [a-Si TFT LCD Single Chip Driver 240RGBx320 Resolution and 262K color Datasheet](http://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/ILI9325.pdf) and tried to read it but I didn't understand much.

And another question, I want to know if it's workable for a beginner or if it's reserved to someone at an advanced level ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This display (according to the provided datasheet) is capable of communicating over SPI, that would make it a candidate to work with the SPI port that is available on the GPIO pins.

But you said that you did not understand very much of the datasheet itself, that might already answer your question. If you don't have any experience with electronics and do not have some tools to investigate on the lowest level what is going on (like a oscilloscope or something) it will be VERY hard to get a thing like this to work.

First you need to get the low level SPI communication to work, this display is not going to tell you if it received the data (only when fully initialized, you'll see output). Having linux to do the SPI communication will help big time.

Second you probably need to send some initialization commands (according to the protocol of this display) to get the display in a state that is usable. (again without any output from the screen)

Third you can send some basic things to the screen and when the steps 1 and 2 were correct it will actually show something.

You see there are some 'blind' steps that need to function correct before you can make some library to make some nice output.

I am NOT saying it is impossible, but it will take a very long time and a LOT of finding stuff out and learning to get it eventually done, if you are willing to invest that amount of dedication and commitment into it, please DO! Maybe you find your new career along the way, (because it IS fun to get it to work, I can assure you that!). But I can also tell you, that there will be times that nothing seems to work because of a tiny little mistake (or some unaccounted/missed variable) and you're ready to throw the whole idea and the display itself into the trash. If you can overcome those barriers and still have FUN doing it, DO IT!

But it might be a very good idea, to get some basic understanding of electronics by trying to make something a little more responsive than an LCD to work. Start with some I2C chips and make them output some data you want on LED's etc etc. those are likely to succeed without too much knowledge to start with, and you'll get some feeling for this stuff.